# How to get lat long after 6m distance from current marker on google maps web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have drawn a polyline(blue color) to a distance and I'm showing some markers on the polyline line to indicate different activities.

I need to change the color of polyline for a distance of 6m from marker to a specific color on my web application.

```
<Map
    google={this.props.google}
    initialCenter={this.state.center}
    center={this.state.center}
    defaultCenter={this.props.center}
    zoom={this.state.zoom}
>
    <Polyline
        fillColor="#669DF6"
        fillOpacity={0.35}
        path={Mapdata}
        strokeColor="#669DF6"
        strokeOpacity={1}
        strokeWeight={6}
    />
    <Marker
        Icon={manuel}
        position={{ lat: 19.0634019, lng: 73.0192121 }}
    />
    <Marker
        Icon={jcbAnomaly}
        position={{ lat: 19.05744544, lng: 73.0296966 }}
    />
    <Marker
        Icon={controlStn}
        position={{ lat: 19.01496242, lng: 72.89882777 }}
    />
</Map>
```

Comment: Please share some code related to what you're trying to do. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Add code snippet